# Static library vs Dynamic library for storing classes

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I was storing my classes in static libraries.For example modify the original header file like adding line pragma comment(lib,"MyClass") then copy files to the visual studio's include and lib folder.Whatever everything was fine until i wanted to add Menu to my class.Lib files does not have resources so i am going to use dynamic link library for this class.Is this logical that storing classes in dlls? also i dont know how to use dlls like that...
is there some examples for this? Also there is classes like CFileDialog that have resources(dialog) this kind of classes use static libraries or dynamic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this sounds like "the wrong place to split things". In other words, if your library needs a resource that is part of the application, then it's probably not meant to be a library in the first place - it is either a proper standalone DLL that contains its own resource, because it has a complete and standalone functionality, or it's actually part of the main executable, and uses the main executable's resource.

The point of making something into a library is that it allows the separation of the library contents from the main application.

Another option is of course that you pass in the relevant resource information from the main application to your class in the library [this works for a a DLL too, of course].

My point here is that a menu is something that belongs to the main application - it knows what it has under `File`, `Edit`, `View`, etc. If you are writing a word processor, you may have things like "Spell checking" in there, but you don't want "Spell checking" in the Photo Editor software, but you probably want some way to get colour profile information to match the monitor's colour balance with the official colours. So your "class" to handle menus probably shouldn't "know" what the menus are, but just how to deal with menus in general - what menus you have comes from the actual main application.

I know this isn't really a direct answer to your questions...

Comment: thank you for your answer i want to create standalone class that doesn't need any other work so i am going to convert it to a dll project.I guess there is nothing else to do.